# python array to sql in clause

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have an array of values in Python that I need to use in an IN clause in a SQL query. The array is not a fixed size. Currently I am using simple string replacement but I would prefer to use named bind variables to avoid sql-injection attacks and so that I can reference the same variable in multiple places in the SQL query:

My current code (simplified excerpt):

```
accts = ['A123', 'B456', 'C789']
acct_list = ','.join(["'%s'" % a for a in accts])
cursor.execute('''
    SELECT A,B,C FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE ACCT_CODE IN ({alist})
    UNION SELECT A,B,C FROM OTHER_TABLE WHERE ACCT_CODE IN ({alist})
'''.format(alist=acct_list))
```

Ideally, I would like to do something like this, but I know it's not this easy:

```
accts = ['A123', 'B456', 'C789']
cursor.execute('''
    SELECT A,B,C FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE ACCT_CODE IN (:alist)
    UNION SELECT A,B,C FROM OTHER_TABLE WHERE ACCT_CODE IN (:alist)
''', alist=accts)
```

The only solution I have thought of so far is this, but this is less than ideal, especially when I have other SQL variables besides this list:

```
accts = ['A123', 'B456', 'C789']
vars = ['acct%d' % int(x+1) for x,a in enumerate(accts)]
vlist = ','.join([':%s' % v for v in vars])
parms = dict(zip(vars, accts))
sql = '''
    SELECT A,B,C FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE ACCT_CODE IN ({vlist})
    UNION SELECT A,B,C FROM OTHER_TABLE WHERE ACCT_CODE IN ({vlist})
'''.format(vlist=vlist)
cursor.execute(sql, parms)
```

The last code block above will allow me to do everything I need to do including adding additional parameters to the query and parms dictionary but it just feels like I going around the barn to do something that shouldn't be so difficult. Before I changed all my code to use this solution, I thought I would see if anyone here knew of a more "proper" way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it for an 'in' clause, but for an insert statement with variable number of items, I do use ? marks multiplied by the number of elements in the list:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO my_table("+','.join([x for x in field_list])+") VALUES("+"?,"*(len(field_list)-1)+"?)", insert_list)
```

So that the actual python insert string looks like this:

```
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO my_table(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', insert_list)
```

Comment: Basically the same as my third example above with numeric positional parameters.  It works but not ideal for the same reasons. I'm going to improve my quest to better explain my issue.